# On mouse click strikethrough Button

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I have a WrapPanel with 3 buttons.

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <Button Content="Book1" />
   <Button Content="Book2" />
   <Button Content="Book3" />
</WrapPanel>
```

If i click on Book1 i see the content for Book1. If i click on Book2 i see the content for Book2 etc. Is there any command that can strikethrough the button if i click on it? In Html there is "del" for text:

```
<del>Strikethrough</del>
```

I want same but in wpf and with Buttons

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add TextDecoration object to TextBlock.TextDecorations collection in click event (for example):

XAML:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click_1">
   <TextBlock>
       Book 1
   </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

And handler:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // ... your logic

   var button = (Button)sender;
   var textBlock = (TextBlock)button.Content;

   // if decoration wasn't already inserted
   //
   if (!textBlock.TextDecorations.Any())
       textBlock.TextDecorations.Add(new TextDecoration { Location = TextDecorationLocation.Strikethrough });
 }
```

UPDATE: answer for your comment - the simplest way

XAML

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Click="Button_Click_1">
            <TextBlock>
                Book 1
            </TextBlock>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name="button2" Click="Button_Click_2">
            <TextBlock>
                Book 2
            </TextBlock>
        </Button>
```

Code:

```
private void SetStrikethrough(Button b, Boolean strikethrough)
        {
            var textBlock = (TextBlock)b.Content;

            if (strikethrough)
            {
                if (!textBlock.TextDecorations.Any())
                    textBlock.TextDecorations.Add(
                        new TextDecoration { Location = TextDecorationLocation.Strikethrough });
            }
            else
            {
                textBlock.TextDecorations.Clear();
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button)sender;
            SetStrikethrough(button1, true);
            SetStrikethrough(button2, false);
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (Button)sender;
            SetStrikethrough(button2, true);
            SetStrikethrough(button1, false);
        }
```

Note that this code is always assumes that a button content is a textblock. Just for simplicity.

Comment: thats almost what i want to do. But if i click on the second Button (Book2) than the "Strikethrough" stays in Button 1(Book1) too.

Comment: You have one event handler on all your buttons or different (1 for each) ?

Comment: I tried first Button_Click_1 for all Buttons. Than i created 2 more for each button . If i click on Button the Strikethrough doesn't disappear from the previous clicked Buttons